# Corrupted stack while testing Doom 3 Stack implementation

Tags: c++, memory, stack, allocation

I get

> Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted.

While trying out this code:

```
    #include "Stack.h"
    #include <iostream>

    struct product {
        int weight;
        float price;
    } ;

    void main(void){
        product a = {1, 4.0f};
        product b = {2, 5.0f};
        product c = {3, 6.0f};

        idStackTemplate<product, sizeof(product)> stack;

        stack.Add(&a);
        stack.Add(&b);
        stack.Add(&c);

        product * first, * second, *third;

        third = stack.Get();
        second = stack.Get();
        first = stack.Get();

        std::cout << first->price << "\t" << first->weight << "\n";
        std::cout << second->price << "\t" << second->weight << "\n";
        std::cout << third->price << "\t" << third->weight << "\n";
    }
```

Stack.h source code is located [here](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3/blob/master/neo/idlib/containers/Stack.h)!

Otherwise the code prints out the correct values.

I'm a beginner/intermediate in c/c++ so can you please help me understand how idStack works and what am I doing wrong.

I have tried creating stack object with idStack(type, next) macro - from what I understand you should put one of the elements of product for "next" parameter so that it calculates offset. It never worked correctly (with either weight or price) although I didn't get any stack corruption errors but the variables didn't print out correctly.

I have also seen some code in Doom 3 source code that uses dynamic allocation with memory pool which would kinda explain this but I can't see this technique being used here...

EDIT: I feel like I shoud allocate enough memory on heap (3*sizeof(a)) with that custom allocators and then initialize a at the beginning of that newly allocated memory. Am I leaning in the right direction?

Comment: Do you need to use the Doom 3 implementation? The C++ standard library has a [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) container.

Comment: I would like to understand the code as part of my learning of c++. I have implemented multiple containers in java and python which are my primary languages and I found out that it's good practice for learning new language to implement some common algorithms and containers.

Comment: That's cool, sorry I don't have an answer for this Doom 3 issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stack implementation is intrusive - it expects that there's a pointer available for the stack template to use.  In this case, the second template argument is intended to have the offset to that pointer - not the size of the object being stored.

So you might make the following modifications:

```
struct product {
    int weight;
    float price;
    struct product* next;   // <-- link pointer field
} ;


// the stack declaration:

idStackTemplate<product, offsetof(struct product, next)> stack;
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It should go without saying that this kind of container is not generally considered good practice.

Comment: So the stack itself isn't really heap allocated but objects themselves can be?

Comment: Objects put on the stack can allocated in any manner, but they must not be destroyed while on the stack. Also, objects should be only on one stack at a time (more precisely - a particular link pointer member should be used only by one stack object at a time).